# How to count only words that start with a Capital in a list?

Tags: c

**How to count words that only start with capitals?**

- Find all uppercase starting words *(eg. Any = 3)*
- Count how many times those words occur *(eg. Any=3 + any+4 = Any=7)*

---

**See the example code from this demonstration:**

https://codeforwin.org/2018/02/c-program-count-occurrences-of-all-words-a-file.html

**Code example:**

https://onlinegdb.com/HJgWn-K2E

```
/**
* C program to count occurrences of all words in a file.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_WORDS   50

char *strlwr(char *str)
{
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)str;

    while (*p) {
        *p = tolower((unsigned char)*p);
        p++;
    }

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char path[100];
    int i, len, index, isUnique;

    // List of distinct words
    char words[MAX_WORDS][50];
    char word[50];

    // Count of distinct words
    int  count[MAX_WORDS];


    /* Input file path */
    printf("Enter file path: ");
    scanf("%s", path);


    /* Try to open file */
    fptr = fopen(path, "r");

    /* Exit if file not opened successfully */
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check you have read privileges.\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Initialize words count to 0
    for (i=0; i<MAX_WORDS; i++)
        count[i] = 0;




    index = 0;

    while (fscanf(fptr, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // Convert word to lowercase
        strlwr(word);

        // Remove last punctuation character
        len = strlen(word);
        if (ispunct(word[len - 1]))
            word[len - 1] = '\0';


        // Check if word exits in list of all distinct words
        isUnique = 1;
        for (i=0; i<index && isUnique; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(words[i], word) == 0)
                isUnique = 0;
        }

        // If word is unique then add it to distinct words list
        // and increment index. Otherwise increment occurrence
        // count of current word.
        if (isUnique)
        {
            strcpy(words[index], word);
            count[index]++;

            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            count[i - 1]++;
        }



    }

    // Close file
    fclose(fptr);


    /*
     * Print occurrences of all words in file.
     */
    printf("\nOccurrences of all distinct words in file: \n");
    for (i=0; i<index; i++)
    {
        /*
         * %-15s prints string in 15 character width.
         * - is used to print string left align inside
         * 15 character width space.
         */
        printf("%-15s %d\n", words[i], count[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

In this code example, they make all words lower case letters then count all those words.

Instead: How do you only add the words to the unique list if it starts with a capital, then count all the occurances of that word

Should you combine **fscanf** with **if (isupper[0])**

**Test.txt file**

```
Any girl jumped over one boy.
Some car skipped to some boy.
One town drove over the town.
Any town ran under some dog.
Some girl drove to a town.
The boy walked under any town.
A town jumped over any car.
Any boy jumped from a car.
A dog ran over a boy.
A girl ran to some car.
A car ran under the girl.
The car ran on any town.
One dog walked under any dog.
A car jumped on some town.
A boy ran to a boy.
The dog drove over a boy.
A boy jumped over the car.
Some car drove on some girl.
One boy drove under some girl.
A girl walked over some dog.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Any  7
Some 3
One  4
The  6
A    8
```

**Current Output:**

```
any             7
girl            7
jumped          5
over            7
one             4
boy             10
some            10
car             9
skipped         1
to              4
town            8
drove           5
the             6
ran             6
under           5
dog             6
a               13
walked          3
from            1
on              3
```

**Possible Solutions:**

```
    // skip the word if it does not contain a capital letter at start
    if (islower(word[0])) {
        continue;
    }
```

Then create another **FOR** loop which checks how often those words appear in the file if they are starting with *lowercase* or *uppercase*

Comment: lookup the function strtok() and isupper(). https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in the correct direction, you just need to rearrange your code a bit. While you can use separate arrays to try and keep track each unique word, while coordinating that index with an index in an array holding the number of times the word occurs and the same index in another array holding whether the word occurs in your file capitalized or not -- but there is a better way.

Whenever you have to coordinate differing types of data as a single-unit, you need to be thinking `struct`. With a `struct`, you can coordinate each unique word, whether it appears capitalized in the file, and the number of times it occurs (case-insensitive) as a single unit, e.g.

```
typedef struct {            /* use a struct to hold */
    char word[MAX_WORD];    /* lowercase word, and */
    int cap, count;         /* if it appeast capitalized, and its count */
} words_t;
```

Now you can simply create an array of `words_t` and be able to add each `word` (lowercase) as the word within the struct, capture whether it ever appears `cap`italized and the total `count` of the times it occurs.

This simplifies the logic in your code. Now you simply declare an array of `words_t`, e.g.

```
#define MAX_WORD     50     /* max word size */
#define MAX_WORDS   512     /* max number of words */
...
    /* Array of struct of distinct words, initialized all zero */
    words_t words[MAX_WORDS] = {{ .word = "" }};
```

You ask for your filename -- ***validating every user input***, e.g.

```
    /* Input file path */
    printf ("Enter file path: ");
    if (scanf ("%s", path) != 1) {  /* validate every input */
        fputs ("error: invalid file path or cancellation.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

Now loop over your words -- while protecting your array bounds as well as reading each word:

```
    while (index < MAX_WORDS &&                 /* protect array bounds  */
            fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1) {   /* while valid word read */
```

Now the crux of the logic needed to store and keep track of which words have appeared capitalized comes into play. First you need a flag to test whether the word appears capitalized to capture the information *before* you convert the word to lowercase (along with your `isunique` flag). You capture whether the word appears capitalized, simply by testing the first character with `isupper()`, e.g.

```
        int iscap = 0, isunique = 1;    /* is captial, is unique flags */

        if (isupper (*word))            /* is the word uppercase */
            iscap = 1;
```

Rather than just trimming a single punctuation, you can just as easily trim *all* punctuation before converting the word to lowercase, e.g.

```
        /* remove all trailing punctuation characters */
        len = strlen (word);                    /* get length */
        while (len && ispunct(word[len - 1]))   /* only if len > 0 */
            word[--len] = 0;

        strlwr (word);                  /* convert word to lowercase */
```

Now all that remains from a data storage standpoint is to loop to determine whether the word `isunique`, and if it **is not**, simply set the `cap` flag if `iscap` is TRUE and increment the count. If it **is** unique, then, after exiting the loop, you copy the word to a new element in your array (using `memcpy` you have the length, no need to scan again) and you do the same thing with `cap` and `count`, incrementing `index` when done,

```
        /* check if word exits in list of all distinct words */
        for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (strcmp(words[i].word, word) == 0) {
                isunique = 0;               /* set unique flag zero */
                if (iscap)                  /* if capital flag set */
                    words[i].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
                words[i].count++;           /* increment word count */
                break;                      /* bail - done */
            }
        }
        if (isunique) { /* if unique, add to array, increment index */
            memcpy (words[index].word, word, len + 1);  /* have len */
            if (iscap)                      /* if cap flag set */
                words[index].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
            words[index++].count++;         /* increment count & index */
        }
    }
    fclose (fptr);  /* close file */
```

All that remains is looping over the elements stored in the array and checking the `.cap` member to determine if the word appears capitalized before printing the word and the number of times it appears (**note:** your **Expected Output:** counts are wrong based on your example text)

```
    /*
     * Print occurrences of all words in file.
     */
    puts ("\nOccurrences of all distinct words with Cap in file:");
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (words[i].cap) {
            strcpy (word, words[i].word);
            *word = toupper (*word);
            /*
             * %-15s prints string in 15 character width.
             * - is used to print string left align inside
             * 15 character width space.
             */
            printf("%-15s %d\n", word, words[i].count);
        }
    }
```

(**note:** the use of `puts` instead of `printf` for `"Occurrences of..."` as there is no conversion needed... a good compiler will optimize this for you)

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
/**
 * C program to count occurrences of all words in a file.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_WORD     50     /* max word size */
#define MAX_WORDS   512     /* max number of words */

#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX   2048     /* max path (defined for Linux in limits.h) */
#endif

typedef struct {            /* use a struct to hold */
    char word[MAX_WORD];    /* lowercase word, and */
    int cap, count;         /* if it appeast capitalized, and its count */
} words_t;

char *strlwr (char *str)    /* no need for unsigned char */
{
    char *p = str;

    while (*p) {
        *p = tolower(*p);
        p++;
    }

    return str;
}

int main (void) {

    FILE *fptr;
    char path[PATH_MAX], word[MAX_WORD];
    size_t i, len, index = 0;

    /* Array of struct of distinct words, initialized all zero */
    words_t words[MAX_WORDS] = {{ .word = "" }};

    /* Input file path */
    printf ("Enter file path: ");
    if (scanf ("%s", path) != 1) {  /* validate every input */
        fputs ("error: invalid file path or cancellation.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    fptr = fopen (path, "r");   /* open file */
    if (fptr == NULL) {         /* validate file open */
        fputs ( "Unable to open file.\n"
                "Please check you have read privileges.\n", stderr);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (index < MAX_WORDS &&                 /* protect array bounds  */
            fscanf (fptr, "%s", word) == 1) {   /* while valid word read */
        int iscap = 0, isunique = 1;    /* is captial, is unique flags */

        if (isupper (*word))            /* is the word uppercase */
            iscap = 1;

        /* remove all trailing punctuation characters */
        len = strlen (word);                    /* get length */
        while (len && ispunct(word[len - 1]))   /* only if len > 0 */
            word[--len] = 0;

        strlwr (word);                  /* convert word to lowercase */

        /* check if word exits in list of all distinct words */
        for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (strcmp(words[i].word, word) == 0) {
                isunique = 0;               /* set unique flag zero */
                if (iscap)                  /* if capital flag set */
                    words[i].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
                words[i].count++;           /* increment word count */
                break;                      /* bail - done */
            }
        }
        if (isunique) { /* if unique, add to array, increment index */
            memcpy (words[index].word, word, len + 1);  /* have len */
            if (iscap)                      /* if cap flag set */
                words[index].cap = iscap;   /* set capital flag in struct */
            words[index++].count++;         /* increment count & index */
        }
    }
    fclose (fptr);  /* close file */

    /*
     * Print occurrences of all words in file.
     */
    puts ("\nOccurrences of all distinct words with Cap in file:");
    for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (words[i].cap) {
            strcpy (word, words[i].word);
            *word = toupper (*word);
            /*
             * %-15s prints string in 15 character width.
             * - is used to print string left align inside
             * 15 character width space.
             */
            printf("%-15s %d\n", word, words[i].count);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your posted input

```
$ ./bin/unique_words_with_cap
Enter file path: dat/girljumped.txt

Occurrences of all distinct words with Cap in file:
Any             7
One             4
Some            10
The             6
A               13
```

(**note:** `"Some/some"` appears `10` times and `"A/a"` appears `13` times instead of the `3/8` shown in your **Expected Output:**, which you can confirm by simple count)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you really appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad to help, let me know if there is anything that you have questions about and I'm happy to explain.

Comment: How do you add malloc for this solution if the question has a bigger file?

Comment: You would replace `words_t words[MAX_WORDS]...` with `words_t *words = malloc (MAX_WORDS * sizeof *words);` to initially allocate `MAX_WORDS` elements. Keep a counter `size_t max_words = MAX_WORDS;` and then `if (index == max_words) { void *tmp = realloc (words, 2 * max_words * sizeof *words); if (!tmp) { perror ("realloc-failed"); break; } words = tmp; max_words *= 2; }`  That is the normal doubling scheme for dynamic memory. That way you can set `#define MAX_WORDS 8` to begin and then just double each time `index == max_words`, `realloc`, validate, and update `max_words *= 2;` That's it.

Comment: How do you "Keep a counter size_t max_words = MAX_WORDS;"

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to implement all that

Comment: 1) you just declare a second variable `words_max = WORDS_MAX;` that will track the total number of elements allocated. When you `realloc`, you can't change the constant `WORDS_MAX`, so you change your `words_max` variable. Your `index` tells you "How many elements are filled". You `words_max` tells you how many are available. When `filled == available`, you `realloc` creating `2 * words_max * sizeof *words` elements and since you used `2 * words_max` above, you must update `words_max *= 2;` at the end of the `realloc` so it now holds correct "available elements" again.

Comment: Any chance you can add that to the answer as a second response? trying to get my head around malloc

Comment: See following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148540/how-to-apply-memory-allocation-to-a-c-program-which-counts-the-amount-of-words-i

Comment: @jaycodez see the answer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148540/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148540/how-to-apply-memory-allocation-to-a-c-program-which-counts-the-amount-of-words-i)